# Cheking out maven project from SCM doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, m2eclipse, maven-scm

Please help me out.
I'm using [image]

this eclipse version.

I have installed the m2e-egit connector as I have a git URL to import the project but when I tried to apply my URL I don't see the SCM type as shown in the picture below and yet the project doesn't import.
[image]

I checked in the m2e marketPlace if the installation did not work, but now I don't even see the SCM Connector here I tried many keywords to search but I don't see it because I think I had installed it successfully.
[image]

But why doesn't it show SCM type as git in my eclipse?
Even after installing the software, it doesn't work.
It should show this way.
[image]

Comment: Your Eclipse is 8 releases behind and also the installed plugins might not be up to date or not work with that old Eclipse. Can your issue be reproduced in the current Eclipse? If yes, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi Howlger, I have updated the same eclipse and tried the same issue replicates and tried using new version eclipse but it only allows JDK version >= v11. i need to use JDK 8

Comment: Current Eclipse 2021-12 supports Java 8 and even much older versions. Java 11 or higher is required to run Eclipse, but that's not something that would be affect you. Get Eclipse with an embedded Java 17 and configure your Java 8 that you have installed on your system in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_.

Comment: Thank you Howlger, That works. I really appreciate the help